# How to reorganize the page using "div" and "css"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure how to move search field with blue button in red rectangle to be right of "Поиск мероприятий:" label?

Here's the code:

```
<style>
    #header {
        border: 4px solid red;
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
        text-align:left;
    }
    #nav {
        border: 4px solid green;
        line-height:20px;
        height:420px;
        width:250px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;          
    }
    #section1 {
        border: 4px solid blue;
        width:700px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;         
    }
    #section2 {
        border: 4px solid brown;
        background-color: gainsboro;
        width:700px;
        float:right;
        padding:5px;         
    }
</style>

<div id="header">
    <h2>Поиск мероприятий:</h2>
    <div id="searchKeyword" class="input-group">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search input-group-addon"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Часть названия мероприятия" ng-model="actionsQuery.searchText" on-enter="queryResult()">
        <!--<span class="input-group-btn" ng-hide="!actionsQuery.searchText">-->
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="queryResult()">Найти мероприятия</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    ...
</div>

<div id="section1">
    ...
</div>

<div id="section2">
    ...
</div>
```

[image: Screen shot]
[image: It looks like this after I've added display: inline-block; I have the page as in screen shot attached.]

Comment: The screen shot is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS [display: inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
#header h2, #searchKeyword{
       display:inline-block;
    }
```

```css
#header {
        border: 4px solid red;
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
        text-align:left;
    }
    #header h2, #searchKeyword{
       display:inline-block;
    }
    #nav {
        border: 4px solid green;
        line-height:20px;
        height:420px;
        width:250px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;          
    }
    #section1 {
        border: 4px solid blue;
        width:700px;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;         
    }
    #section2 {
        border: 4px solid brown;
        background-color: gainsboro;
        width:700px;
        float:right;
        padding:5px;         
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h2>Поиск мероприятий:</h2>
    <div id="searchKeyword" class="input-group">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search input-group-addon"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Часть названия мероприятия" ng-model="actionsQuery.searchText" on-enter="queryResult()">
        <!--<span class="input-group-btn" ng-hide="!actionsQuery.searchText">-->
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="queryResult()">Найти мероприятия</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    ...
</div>

<div id="section1">
    ...
</div>

<div id="section2">
    ...
</div>
```

Or Use [float - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```
#header h2, #searchKeyword{
   float:left;
}
```

```css
#header {
    border: 4px solid red;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:left;
    overflow: auto;
}
#header h2, #searchKeyword{
   float:left;
}
#searchKeyword{
   line-height:64px;
}
#nav {
    border: 4px solid green;
    line-height:20px;
    height:420px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
#section1 {
    border: 4px solid blue;
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;         
}
#section2 {
    border: 4px solid brown;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    width:700px;
    float:right;
    padding:5px;         
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h2>Поиск мероприятий:</h2>
    <div id="searchKeyword" class="input-group">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search input-group-addon"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Часть названия мероприятия" ng-model="actionsQuery.searchText" on-enter="queryResult()">
        <!--<span class="input-group-btn" ng-hide="!actionsQuery.searchText">-->
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="queryResult()">Найти мероприятия</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    ...
</div>

<div id="section1">
    ...
</div>

<div id="section2">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Your original answer using floats is a valid approach.

Comment: Add `#header {overflow: auto}` to make sure the floats are contained within the header, otherwise the rest of the layout may break.

Comment: It moved, but not properly. How to display new screen shot?

Comment: new screen shot ? what do you mean?

Comment: It doesn't work properly. I want to show how it looks now after I've added display:inline-block;

Comment: I've added above the screen shot how it looks like now.

Comment: But no seach button the HTML is incomplete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61754/discussion-between-tesicg-and-tambo).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/o2tkn8pL/

You have to make sure that the width of the divs isn't bigger than the screen size.
So using fixed width is not a good idea in my opinion. Use percent values and your design will also be more responsive

Example:

```
width:25%;
```

E: Hmm I think I missunderstood the original question... I thought OP wants the blue div to be inbetween the navigation and the brown div
So to answer the question:
Use

```
#header h2, #searchKeyword{
       display:inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `display: inline-block` to your css:

```
#searchKeyword, h2 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I did it and search field moved right of label, but you can see how it looks like now in second screen shot above.